# Neo4J Cypher: create relationship only if destination node exists

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases, memgraphdb

I am trying to load a csv file that and as part of import try to create a relationship if the foreign key fields are resolved.

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (d1:Destination1 { id: line[2], name: line[3] })
OPTIONAL MATCH (d2:Destination2 { id: line[4], name: line[5] })
MERGE (n:Source {id: line[0])-[:MY_RELATIONSHIP]->(d1)
MERGE (n:Source {id: line[0])-[:MY_RELATIONSHIP]->(d2)
```

this query fails when either of d1 or d2 are not resolved. Is there a way to have a `IF THEN` option to create a link only if the destination exists. I see even `WHERE` clause is not allowed in the `MERGE` statement.

**UPDATE 1**

Looks like I over simplified my query, to give better context, here is what I am planning to achieve:

```
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///MyData.csv' AS line
MATCH (n:BOM { Material: line[0]})
WITH n, line
MATCH (s:Supplier { name:line[2]})
MATCH (t:Type { name: line[7]})
MATCH (g1:Grade { number: line[6]})
MATCH (g2:Grade { number: line[5]})
MERGE (n)-[:HAS_SUPPLIER]->(s)
MERGE (n)-[:MATERIAL_TYPE]->(t)
MERGE (n)-[:HAS_GRADE{priority:1}]->(g1)
MERGE (n)-[:HAS_GRADE{priority:2}]->(g2)
```

I notice that if the query fails to find either `g1` or `g2` it fully fails to update other relationships. I had to resort to `Optional Match` but then the `Merge` fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the only thing you are doing is creating a relationship between existing nodes, then simply change the `OPTIONAL MATCH` to `MATCH` clause

```
MATCH (d1:Destination1 { id: line[2], name: line[3] })
MATCH (d2:Destination2 { id: line[4], name: line[5] })
....
```

You can think of it as this, if a MATCH clause fails to retrieve any data, then the query execution stops for that particular row. In a sense it is doing the same as:

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (d1:Destination1 { id: line[2], name: line[3] })
OPTIONAL MATCH (d2:Destination2 { id: line[4], name: line[5] })
WITH d1, d2
WHERE d1 IS NOT NULL and d2 IS NOT NULL
....
```

If you need to do other things as well, you can resort to `FOREACH` tricks or subqueries.

```
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///MyData.csv' AS line
MATCH (n:BOM { Material: line[0]})
WITH n, line
MATCH (s:Supplier { name:line[2]})
MATCH (t:Type { name: line[7]})
OPTIONAL MATCH (g1:Grade { number: line[6]})
OPTIONAL MATCH (g2:Grade { number: line[5]})
MERGE (n)-[:HAS_SUPPLIER]->(s)
MERGE (n)-[:MATERIAL_TYPE]->(t)
FOREACH (_ in CASE WHEN g2 is not null and g1 is not null THEN [1] ELSE [] END | 
  MERGE (n)-[:HAS_GRADE{priority:1}]->(g1)
  MERGE (n)-[:HAS_GRADE{priority:2}]->(g2))
```

FOREACH trick has been around since forewer (https://data-xtractor.com/blog/databases/neo4j-cypher-hacks/#4_Conditional_Execution_with_8230FOREACH)

Maybe a more clean version would be to use a subquery. I think the following should work:

```
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///MyData.csv' AS line
MATCH (n:BOM { Material: line[0]})
WITH n, line
MATCH (s:Supplier { name:line[2]})
MATCH (t:Type { name: line[7]})
OPTIONAL MATCH (g1:Grade { number: line[6]})
OPTIONAL MATCH (g2:Grade { number: line[5]})
MERGE (n)-[:HAS_SUPPLIER]->(s)
MERGE (n)-[:MATERIAL_TYPE]->(t)
WITH n, g1, g2
CALL {
  WITH n, g1, g2
  WITH *
  WHERE g1 IS NOT NULL and g2 IS NOT NULL 
  MERGE (n)-[:HAS_GRADE{priority:1}]->(g1)
  MERGE (n)-[:HAS_GRADE{priority:2}]->(g2)}
```

You can also obviously create two FOREACH subqueries or two subqueries if you want to link to grade1 if it exists but grade 2 does not exists.

```
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///MyData.csv' AS line
MATCH (n:BOM { Material: line[0]})
WITH n, line
MATCH (s:Supplier { name:line[2]})
MATCH (t:Type { name: line[7]})
OPTIONAL MATCH (g1:Grade { number: line[6]})
OPTIONAL MATCH (g2:Grade { number: line[5]})
MERGE (n)-[:HAS_SUPPLIER]->(s)
MERGE (n)-[:MATERIAL_TYPE]->(t)
FOREACH (_ in CASE WHEN g1 is not null  THEN [1] ELSE [] END | 
  MERGE (n)-[:HAS_GRADE{priority:1}]->(g1))
FOREACH (_ in CASE WHEN g2 is not null  THEN [1] ELSE [] END | 
  MERGE (n)-[:HAS_GRADE{priority:2}]->(g2))
```

Comment: Thanks!, I see what you mean, however if I remove the `Optional Match` then the complete query fails. I have updated the question to give more context. Any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks again, FOREACH did the trick. Hope its not very costly query to execute.